# React Formik updating one field based on another

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm using [formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) react library and trying to update one field, based on the `onChange` event of another.  For example I have one field called `email` with `onChange={onEmailChange.bind(this, setFieldValue)}`.

This is calling the following function when email is changed:

```
const onEmailChange = (setFieldValue, e) => {
  const domain = e.target.value.replace(/.*@/, '')
  setFieldValue('domain', domain, false)
}
```

The idea here is to update the `domain` field with the domain name from the email.  But in any case, the issue here is that using `setFieldValue` seems to prevent the `email` field which is calling the `onChange` from updating.

Any suggestions how to handle this?

Answer (score 5):

You will have to use state to make the input field controlled to handle your character replacing issue.
In your constructor set initial state as,

```
this.state={
 email:""
}
```

Change your onChange as,

```
  <input
      type="email"
      name="email"
      onChange={(ev)=>this.setState({email:ev.target.value})}
      onBlur={()=>onEmailChange()}
      value={this.state.email}
    />
```

use `this.onEmailChange` and `this.setFieldValue` if they are member functions
and onEmailChange function as,

```
const onEmailChange = () => {
  const domain = this.state.email.replace(/.*@/, '')
  this.setFieldValue('domain', domain, false)
}
```

Comment: Hm. Not sure what the difference is here? You're just passing `event` as appose to binding `this`.  In any case, I tried it with same results.  Calling the `setFieldValue` is the issue.

Comment: No, first you have sent the order in reverse and also you are not sending the event, instead `this`.

Comment: Did you try this code? If so what is the error now?

Comment: Yeah I tried the code exactly, its the same result.  It updates the `domain` field, but as you type in the `email` field, it only does 1 letter and keeps replacing itself.  So if you type `abc` it will be like `a`, replace with `b`, replaced with `c`.

Comment: Also, just fyi when passing `this` within `onChange`, `this` is the event.

Comment: Thanks, i see the update, but this is really specific to formik library.  It doesn't work the same way as just a native form using state.

Comment: I took the <input/> from formik's official documentation

Comment: Do you have a reference to that? This is a little different, also would update onBlur as oppose to onChange, which isn't the desired functionality.

Comment: Ok I found the issue, in Formik the native `handleChange` uses `setState` internally to set the field being changed to itself, so since we're using a custom function `onChange`, we need to not only use `setFieldValue` on the target field we're updating, but also use `setFieldValue` on the source field, so in this case `email`.

Answer (score 3):

Formik now has a good example in their documentation regarding dependent fields

https://formik.org/docs/examples/dependent-fields

Comment: See this answer for a simplified example, or if that link ever breaks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69229898/9154668

Comment: This example is not about using fieldArray in formik. I am trying to have a dependent value based on fieldArray.