# NextJS and Formik: Conditional / Dynamic rendering form fields on select dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, next.js, formik

I have a problem with conditional rendering with `Next.js` and `Formik` on my webpage.

So I have an array named `commands` on my page, it's quite easy:

```
const commands = [
    {
        value: 'launch',
        display_name: 'LAUNCH ROCKET!',
    },
    {
        value: 'delay_launch',
        display_name: 'LAUNCH IN..',
    },
    {
      ....list of elements, they are not API fetched!
    }
];
```

And it's need for a web-form (component) on my page (which is based on [Formik](https://formik.org/))

The component is looks like this:

```
<Container>
    <Formik
        initialValues={{ command: 'launch', arguments: 'test'}}
        onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            await setSubmitting(false);
            await Router.push(`/${values.command}`);
        }}
    >
    {({
            values,
            errors,
            touched,
            handleChange,
            handleBlur,
            handleSubmit,
            /* and other goodies */
        }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate autoComplete="off">
            <Grid container spacing={3} direction="row" justify="center" alignItems="center">
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                    <TextField
                        name="command"
                        select
                        label="Select command"
                        className={classes.dropdown}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        value={values.command}
                        variant="outlined"
                    >
                        {commands.map((option) => (
                            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                                {option.label}
                            </MenuItem>
                        ))}
                    </TextField>
                </Grid>
                {/* IF COMMAND IN SELECT DROPDPWN === LAUNCH THEN RENDER THIS*/}
                {values.command === "launch" && (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <Grid item xs={3}>
                            <TextField
                                text-field
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={1}>
                            <Typography variant="h3" align="center" style={{textTransform: 'uppercase', margin: '0'}}>
                                @
                            </Typography>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={3}>
                            <TextField
                                another text-field
                            </TextField>
                        </Grid>
                    </React.Fragment>
                )}
            </Grid>
        </form>
    )}
    </Formik>
</Container>
```

#### How does it (should) work?

*When you select dropdown on page (in Formik's form), it renders other fields, depended on select value*.

#### The problem:

As you may see, it I continue write code like this, it will be the same, as if I write every `if` statement one-by-one.

So if my list of commands have 10+ different commands, it will 10+ `if` blocks. But I don't need to render them all-at-once in my form, with `commands.map =>`. I want to see only those fields in my form that is needed, only when the correct command if selected in `dropdown`.

Like this *(pseudo-code style)*:

```
IF IN MY FORM SELECTED COMMAND:
  LAUNCH => THEN ADD 2 ADDITIONAL FIELDS IN THIS FORM
  DELAYED LAUNCH => THEN ADD 3 ADDITIONAL FIELDS IN THIS FORM
  ...
```

So how to achieve this?

I guess I should add 3-rd field in my array of `commands`, like:

```
const commands = [
    {
        value: 'launch',
        display_name: 'LAUNCH ROCKET!',
        render_code: `<React.Fragment>
                        <Grid item xs={3}>
                            <TextField
                                text-field
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={1}>
                            <Typography variant="h3" align="center" style={{textTransform: 'uppercase', margin: '0'}}>
                                @
                            </Typography>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={3}>
                            <TextField
                                another text-field
                            </TextField>
                        </Grid>
                    </React.Fragment>`
    },
    ....
]
```

But how to render it in my form based on determined selected value? I guess there should be something like: [`Map.get(number)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get), but I haven't found any example, and more then that, I do not know how exactly rendering code fragment should be stored in array. If I store it in a `string` value, is it ok?

#### Updated:

I am trying to use `render_code` example, like one above, via:

```
{commands.find(x => {if (x.value === values.command) return x.rendring_code})}
```

But the problem is that if a store a JSX fragment as `string` it becomes something like:

```
code: "<React.Fragment>\n                <Grid item xs={3}>\n
```

With all this `\n` for line skip and other formatting symbols, but I can't store pure `JSX` because in that case I have a rendering error, cause `<TextField>` have properties like `onChange={handleChange}` which is declared/defined only inside `Formik` form, but not outside the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a relevant problem here, at Formik's Github [Issue #751](https://github.com/formik/formik/issues/751) and at [this article](http://www.fullstackstudent.com/dynamic-react-form-with-formik/). So I have found a bit different, but relevant solution of my problem.

Here is at a [snippet @CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/formik-example-3jfxh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) and [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60517777/how-can-i-create-connected-dependent-select-elements-in-formik) for that.

So the solution is based on sub-component for original form, which is rendered based on select field. (Just exactly what I needed).

Unfortunately I doesn't solve the duplicate code problem, but at structuring the code well and renders only the necessary part of the form.