# Re-populate a Select dropdown depending on another selection in a Formik form

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, formik

I have two dropdowns where selecting an option on the right should update the options on the left.
[image]

The 1st one is `frequencyDays`, the 2nd is `frequencyInterval`.

Suppose I have a function that will return an array of `<option>`s for a given ID (the value of the 2nd param)

```
const getOptionsDays = (value) => {
    let options = [];
    //... some logic in a loop ...
    for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
       options.push(<option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>);
    }
    return options; // Returns an array of <option> elements
}
```

The Formik form pre-populates correctly on initialization, but does not update.

**First Dropdown (frequencyDays)**

```
<Form.Control as="select"
  id="dropdownFrequencyDays"
  name="frequencyDays"
  value={values.frequencyDays}
  onChange={handleChange}
>
    <option></option>
    { getOptionsForDays(values.frequencyInterval) }
</Form>
```

**Second Dropdown (frequencyInterval), onChange should trigger repopulation**

```
<Form.Control as="select"  
              id="dropdownFrequencyInterval"
              name="frequencyInterval"
              value={values.frequencyInterval}
              onChange={e => /* Should do something here but getting syntax errors */
                         // Call built-in Formik handleChange 
                         handleChange(e);
                         // Additional: call to repopulate 1st dropdown?
                         // ...errors
                       }
>
```

I want to let Formik do its form binding but in addition call the repopulation of the 1st dropdown, but getting errors.

Comment: See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60517777/how-can-i-create-connected-dependent-select-elements-in-formik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close. The solution is to keep a state var. with your `<option>` array. Then `onChange`, remember the syntax is `onChange={e => { .. }}` (double brace), includes both the default Formik `handleChange` + custom state setter.

```
// State var to keep option array
const [frequencyDayValues, setFrequencyDayValues] = useState([]);

...

// On initialization, set your option array (with whatever logic needed, 
// e.g. populateOptions() for an initial code of 55)
useEffect(() => {    
    setFrequencyDayValues(populateOptions(55));
}, []);

// The option array must contain actual <option> elements, e.g.
const populateOptions = (value) => {
    let options = [];
    options.push(<option value={..}>Label</option>);
    return options;
}
...

{/* Dependent Dropdown: Displays whatever is currently in frequencyDayValues */}
<Form.Control as="select"
              name="frequencyDays"
              value={values.frequencyDays}
              onChange={handleChange}
>
    <option></option>
    {/* Populate Frequency Days from current state variable */}
    {frequencyDayValues}
</Form.Control>

{/* Triggering Dropdown: onChange does both the Formik handleChange AND custom update */}
<Form.Control as="select" 
              name="frequencyInterval"
              value={values.frequencyInterval}
              onChange={e => {
                  // Call default Formik handleChange()
                  handleChange(e);
                  // Additionally set the new frequencyDayValues state variable
                  // based on e.target.value
                  setFrequencyDayValues(populateOptions(e.target.value));
                }
              }                                                      
>
```